# Searching polygon on 2D coordinate system

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for an algorythm and a data structure for representing a polygons on a 2D coordinate system, and searching for the last polygon that contains a given point with O(logn) complexity.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by the "last polygon that contains a given point"?

Comment: The one with a node that has the biggest X value for example